# Diferença entre './', '../' e '/'

Tags: php, sistema-de-arquivos

Em alguns códigos que trabalho, as vezes não existe uma variavel global que aponte para a raiz do projeto, tal como:

```
$RAIZ='PATH/EXAMPLE/';
```

Então frequentemente usam:

```
src='./somePath';
src='../somePath';
src='/somePath';
```

Qual a diferença?

O que acontece com arquivos de outros diretorios que foram incluidos (include) e precisam acessar recursos do diretorio local?

Exemplo:

```
|a.php -> inclui ('pasta/b.php') 
|pasta/b.php -> acessa ('img.png')
|pasta/img.png
```

Comment: Uma dica off amigo, para evitar problemas com inclusões de diferentes locais, o melhor é colocar o caminho todo nos includes. Como por exemplo `define('FULL_PATH', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . '/'); include FULL_PATH . 'pasta/meu-arquivo.php';`. Use este `define` apenas em um arquivo na pasta raiz do teu projeto, para acessar está "constante", inclua ela em uma arquivo global e inclua este arquivo em outros :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Cada um desses muda a forma como um diretório é referenciado.

Suponhamos um arquivo `teste.txt`:

- `/teste.txt`: significa que o arquivo `teste.txt` está na pasta raiz do sistema;
- `./teste.txt`: significa que o arquivo `teste.txt` está na mesma pasta que o script está rodando;
- `../teste.txt`: significa que o arquivo `teste.txt` está na pasta imediatamente acima da pasta em que o script PHP está rodando.

Em qualquer linguagem de programação, é sempre importante referenciar arquivos em relação ao diretório raiz da *aplicação*, e não em relação ao *sistema*, para evitar confusões. Com isso você garante portabilidade à aplicação, que pode rodar em qualquer sistema ou estrutura de diretórios, independente de seu sistema de arquivos.

Comment: Sua última frase define tudo, na aplicação sempre ter o caminho absoluto pode ajudar a evitar muitas dores de cabeça +1

Answer (score 16):

Tendo a estrutura de pasta a baixo:

[image: Estrutura de pastas modelo]

Levando em consideração que estou no arquivo `conteúdo.html` e quiser incluir o arquivo `horas.html`, como os dois estão no mesmo no mesmo nível de pastas então eu deverei usar:

```
include "./horas.html";
```

Para incluir o arquivo `dicas.html` que está na pasta `recursos` deverei usar:

```
include "./recursos/dicas.html";
```

Já que a pasta `recursos` está no mesmo nível que `conteúdo.html`

Agora para incluir o arquivo `catálogo.html` que está na pasta `produtos` deverei usar:

```
include "../produtos/catálogo.html";
```

Sendo assim eu irei subir um nível entre as pastas e a partir daí inserir o caminho do arquivo desejado.

Mas sabendo que a pasta `produtos` é uma pasta que está na pasta raiz eu posso usar:

```
include "/produtos/catálogo.html";
```

### Sendo assim

Em `src='./somePath';` o `./` significa que você está referenciando à pasta atual

Em `src='../somePath';` o `../` significa que você está referenciando uma pasta anterior a atual. Você pode utilizar vários para buscar em pastas em níveis diferentes.
**Exemplo:** 
`src='../../../otherPath';` aqui estou buscando a pasta `otherPath` em uma pasta que está 3 níveis acima da pasta onde o script atual está rodando.

Em `src='/somePath';` 0 `/` significa que você está se referenciando à pasta raiz do sistema

Answer (score -6):

Uma maneira simples:

Considere a Pasta Raiz como DirZero...

No arquivo que está sendo trabalhado (independente do Diretório), e irá incluir o `arquivoincluido.php` que está dois níveis abaixo da raíz:

```
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/DirNivel1/DirNivel2/arquivoincluir.php');
```