# erro: "failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Tags: php

Estou pegando os dados de uma tela de formulário.

```
<?php
include_once '../model/dao/FitaDao.php';
include_once '../model/vo/FitaVO.php';
include_once '../model/vo/FilmeVO.php';
include_once '../model/vo/CategoriaFilmeVO.php';
include_once '../model/vo/ArtistaVO.php';


class FitaController {

  public function insereFita(FitaVo $fita){
    $fd = new FitaDao();
    $fd->insereMidia($fita);
  }

}

  switch($_POST['acao']){

    case 1:{
      $categoria = new CategoriaFilmeVO($_POST['categoria']);
      $artista = new ArtistaVO($_POST['artista'], $_POST['data']);
      $filme = new FilmeVO($_POST['titulo'], $categoria);
      $filme->adicionaArtistas($artista);
      $fita = new FitaVO($_POST['formato'], $_POST['ano'], $filme);

      $fc = new FitaController();
      $fc->insereFita($fita);
      break;
  }

}
?>
```

Até ai tudo bem, só que quando chamo a classe `fitaDao`, ele não consegue encontrar o caminho da classe `Conexao`.

```
<?php
require_once "../../conexao/Conexao.php";
include_once '../vo/CategoriaFilmeVO.php';
include_once '../vo/ArtistaVO.php';
include_once '../vo/FilmeVO.php';
include_once '../vo/FitaVO.php';

class FitaDao {

  private $conexao;

  function __construct(){
    $conexao = new Conexao();
    $this->conexao = $conexao->conectar();
    $this->conexao->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
  }
?>
```

Gerando o erro:

> Warning: require_once(../../conexao/Conexao.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\vintagelocadora\app\model\dao\FitaDao.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../../conexao/Conexao.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\vintagelocadora\app\model\dao\FitaDao.php on line 2

Segue imagem do meu diretório:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recomendo para "evitar conflitos" que crie na sua index.php uma constante que deve ter o caminho completo até aquele ponto e essa constante será usado nos includes, assim:

index.php:

```
<?php
//usei o __FILE__ ao invés de __DIR__ devido a algunas questões de retrocompatibilidade

define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));

...
```

Acredito que todos arquivos são chamados pelo index.php, então não precisa fazer nada além disto:

No FitaDao.php faça assim:

```
<?php
require_once ROOT_PATH . "/conexao/Conexao.php";
include_once ROOT_PATH . '/model/vo/CategoriaFilmeVO.php';
include_once ROOT_PATH . '/model/vo/ArtistaVO.php';
include_once ROOT_PATH . '/model/vo/FilmeVO.php';
include_once ROOT_PATH . '/model/vo/FitaVO.php';

class FitaDao {

  private $conexao;

  function __construct(){
    $conexao = new Conexao();
    $this->conexao = $conexao->conectar();
    $this->conexao->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
  }
} //Faltava um } no final
```

E no formulário:

```
<?php
include_once ROOT_PATH . '/model/dao/FitaDao.php';
include_once ROOT_PATH . '/model/vo/FitaVO.php';
include_once ROOT_PATH . '/model/vo/FilmeVO.php';
include_once ROOT_PATH . '/model/vo/CategoriaFilmeVO.php';
include_once ROOT_PATH . '/model/vo/ArtistaVO.php';

class FitaController {

  public function insereFita(FitaVo $fita){
    $fd = new FitaDao();
    $fd->insereMidia($fita);
  }

}

  switch($_POST['acao']){

    case 1:{
      $categoria = new CategoriaFilmeVO($_POST['categoria']);
      $artista = new ArtistaVO($_POST['artista'], $_POST['data']);
      $filme = new FilmeVO($_POST['titulo'], $categoria);
      $filme->adicionaArtistas($artista);
      $fita = new FitaVO($_POST['formato'], $_POST['ano'], $filme);

      $fc = new FitaController();
      $fc->insereFita($fita);
      break;
  }

}
?>
```

Comment: vlw cara era isso mesmo, muito obrigado

Comment: @RodrigoJacinto tudo bem querer `../../`, mas vai por mim, isso lhe causará mais dificuldades do semelhantes.

Comment: @RodrigoJacinto acho a solução apresentada pelo Guilherme mais adequada. Minha resposta resolve o problema diretamente mas levanta outra questão que poderá surgir no futuro se a sua classe for reaproveitada, mas tudo bem, vocẽ escolhe a resposta mais adequada ao seu problema.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento então a resposta do felipe deus menos dor de cabeça para arrumar o código, mas vejo que a sua resolverá meu problemas futuros tbm, agradeço

Comment: @RodrigoJacinto desculpa, pode marcar a dele, mas a questão de dor de cabeça e vai da limitação de conhecimento (o quanto você já conhece) x entendimento (o que entendeu da minha explicação), essa perguntas resposta**s** devem lhe ajudar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60455/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Tudo bem agradeço

Answer (score 1):

O arquivo `FitaController.php` faz o include do ficheiro `FitaDao.php` que por sua vez faz o include do ficheiro `Conexao.php`, entretanto o caminho deve ser relativo ao primeiro include, ou seja, em relação ao `FitaController.php`.

No seu arquivo `FitaDao.php` troque:

```
require_once "../../conexao/Conexao.php";
```

Por:

```
require_once "../conexao/Conexao.php";
```

Mas essa solução representa um problema, se a sua classe for incluída (portanto reaproveitada) em outros arquivos em diretórios diferentes, o mesmo problema irá ocorre se o diretório estiver num nível diferente do diretório `controller`.

Uma das soluções seria utilizar [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).