# como inserir uma imagem pelo css?

Tags: css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero inserir no meu arquivo style.css uma imagem que esta dentro da pasta images que esta dentro da minha pasta assets. qual caminho tenho que descrever pra alcançar esse diretorio?

Comment: Olá, bem vindo. Por favor, opte por postar o código e não imagens do código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stephan básicamente vc tem que voltar uma pasta para cima usando os `../` e caindo na raiz da `pasta assets` depois vc tem que entrar na pasta `/images`, depois procurar sua imagem dentro da pasta `/nome-imagem.jpg`

Então seu caminho ficaria assim: `url(../imagens/nome-imagem.jpg)`

Leia essa Resposta que vai te ajudar muito a entender melhor como funciona essa "navegação" pelas pastar do projeto [Diferença entre './', '../' e '/'](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-e/60458#60458)

Comment: muito obrigado, funcionou certinho rs!!!

Comment: @StephanViana que bom que deu certo! Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da minha resposta :) assim o site não fica com perguntas abertas pendentes sem resposta aceita.

Answer (score 0):

Não dá para inserir imagens pelo css 
O css serve somente para fazer o design do site!
Para inserir a imagem tem de ser por **html**, este é um exemplo de como colocar

```
<img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket">
```

para aceder à pasta é indicar o caminho exemplo: `<img src="../data/imagens/picture.jpg ...`