# Receber dados $POST para validar login

Tags: php, mvc, classes, post, php-7

Uma ajudinha hehe

Estou tendo dificuldades em criar uma validação de login em um padrão **MVC**.

Acho que consegui estruturar certo e minha tela de login aparecer na index. Até ai tudo okay.

Quando eu submeto o form que começa minha dor de cabeça, segue os códigos:

**Quando submeto o form, retorna o seguinte erro:**

```
Warning: include_once(MODEL/Model.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xamppNew\htdocs\futamador\CONTROLLER\ControllerLogin.php on line 2
Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'MODEL/Model.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xamppNew\php\PEAR') in C:\xamppNew\htdocs\futamador\CONTROLLER\ControllerLogin.php on line 2
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Model' not found in C:\xamppNew\htdocs\futamador\CONTROLLER\ControllerLogin.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\xamppNew\htdocs\futamador\CONTROLLER\ControllerLogin.php(27): ControllerLogin->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xamppNew\htdocs\futamador\CONTROLLER\ControllerLogin.php on line 14
```

**Index**

```
if (isset($_POST[''])){
    throw new Exception("Erro ao carregar <b>index.php</b>");
} else {
    include_once("CONTROLLER/Controller.php");

    $controller = new Controller();
    $controller->login();
}
```

**Controller**

```
include_once("MODEL/Model.php");    

class Controller {  

    public $model;
    public $view;
    private $usuario;
    private $senha;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->model = new Model();
    }

    public function login(){
        include_once("VIEW/login.php");
    }       
}
```

**ControllerLogin**

```
include_once("..\MODEL\Model.php");

class ControllerLogin {
    private $model;
    private $usuario;
    private $senha;

    function __construct(){
        if( isset($_POST )){
            $this->usuario = $_POST['usuario'] ? $_POST['usuario'] : null;
            $this->senha = $_POST['senha'] ? $_POST['senha'] : null;

            $this->model = new Model();
            validaLogin( $this->usuario, $this->senha );

        } else {
            throw new Exception("Erro ao receber dados para login (<b>ControllerLogin.php</b>.");               
        }   
    }

    private function validaLogin($usuario, $senha){
        $this->model->exibirDados($usuario, $senha);
    }
}

new ControllerLogin();
```

**Model**

```
include_once("MODEL/ConexaoContaModel.php");

class Model extends ConexaoConta {      
    function __construct(){         
    }

    public function exibirDados($usuario, $senha){
        echo $usuario . " - " . $senha;
    }
}
```

**Form do Login da View**

```
<form method="POST" action="CONTROLLER/ControllerLogin.php">
    <h2>Login</h2>

    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Usuário</label>     
    <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Digitar o Usuário" required autofocus><br />

    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Senha</label>
    <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Digite a Senha" required >

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Acessar</button>
  </form>
```

Me perdoem o post imenso! Mas ficaria grato por um luz :)

Comment: O arquivo `Model.php` esta um diretório acima do diretório *CONTROLLER*? Então o correto é `include_once("../MODEL/Model.php");`

Comment: As pastas estão assim: **RAIZ** > CONTROLLER | MODEL | VIEW | Index.php. Na pasta **CONTROLLER** > Controller.php, ControllerLogin.php

Comment: Leia essa pergunta e a resposta: [Diferença entre './', '../' e '/'](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60455)

Comment: @NoobSaibot muito obrigado! Não tinha percebido. Dei um `__DIR__` e vi que o caminho realmente não existia. Ainda retorna erro, mas é relacionado a outra parte do código

Comment: Caso necessite de ajuda com esse outro erro, pode criar uma nova pergunta. Abri votação para fechar essa pergunta.

Comment: @NoobSaibot Obrigadão! O outro erra era porque faltou um `this->`  no construtor do meu ControllerLogin.php quando chamou o método `validaLogin()`

Comment: Pra quem tiver o mesmo problema de rota dos arquivos, usar o caminho completo, ajuda muito ( `C:/pasta/pasta/pasta/arquivo.php` ou `https://meusite/pasta/arquivo.php` ).